# How we can Swipe Home screen Over Transparent Activity?

Tags: android

I am Making a Android App Like Screen Crack.
I have Made Transparent Activity which over on Android Home Screen.
I am getting problem When My Transparent Activity Run on Home Screen Then I could not swipe Screen. Please Help me How Can I swipe home screen over transparent Activity.
Thanks

Comment: what you have tried..?

Comment: will you please share your code.?

Comment: Like Crack Screen App .

Comment: Probably they use a system like the facebook heads, dont remember how to find this solution.